# Move view up to a specific layout element when opening keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-constraintlayout

I have this webview with an input field at the bottom.

on top and bottom of the screen are native view elements.

When I open now the keyboard when tapping on the webview input field the keyboard opens and moves the view up including the bottom navigation.

Can I move the layout up so the keyboard still overlaps the bottom navigation?
[image: current state]

As an example here in the google calendar app the description field almost at the bottom of the (list?) view moves up hiding the one below when tapping inside it.

[image: google calendar example]

[image: google calendar example keyboard opened]

Or is that only possible because it's in a listview?